How to style a iframe scrollbar in vue when utilziing a reactive variable for contents
I am loading an email template in to my application using the following code:
  <v-col class="px-10">
    <div v-if="selectedEmailLoading" class="h-100 w-100 d-flex justify-center align-center">
      <v-progress-circular
        color="primary"
        indeterminate
        :size="85"
        :width="12"
      ></v-progress-circular>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="selected-email overflow-hidden d-flex flex-column" style="height: calc(100vh - 240px);">
      <div class="email-header-info">
        <div class="from d-flex my-2">
          <div class="font-weight-bold pr-3 text-h6">
            {{currentEmail?.subject}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="avatar ma-5">
            <v-avatar color="primaryLighten1" size="x-large">
              <span class="text-h5">{{currentEmail?.from.name ? currentEmail?.from.name.split(",").slice(0, 2).map((n: any[])=>n[0]).join("") : ""}}</span>
            </v-avatar>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-info">
            <div class="from d-flex my-2">
              <div class="font-weight-regular text-h6">
                {{currentEmail?.from.name +' <' + currentEmail?.from.email_address + '>'}}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="to d-flex my-2 flex-wrap">
              <div class="font-weight-medium mr-3">
                To:
              </div>
              <span v-for="contact in currentEmail?.to" class="text-subtitle-1 text-grey-darken-1 pr-2">
                {{ contact.name + ';'}}
                <v-tooltip
                  activator="parent"
                  location="top"
                  color="primary"
                >{{contact.email_address}}</v-tooltip>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div v-if="currentEmail?.cc.length > 0" class="cc d-flex my-2 flex-wrap">
              <div class="font-weight-medium mr-3">
                Cc:
              </div>
              <span v-for="contact in currentEmail?.cc" class="text-subtitle-1 text-grey-darken-1 pr-2">
                {{ contact.name + ';'}}
                <v-tooltip
                  activator="parent"
                  location="top"
                  color="primary"
                >{{contact.email_address}}</v-tooltip>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="cc d-flex my-2 flex-wrap">
              <v-chip v-for="attachment in currentEmail?.file_attachments" prepend-icon="mdi-paperclip" size="large" color="primary" class="ma-2" @click="loadAttachment(currentEmail, attachment)">
                {{attachment.file_name.length > 20 ? attachment.file_name.slice(0, 20) + '...' : attachment.file_name}}
                <v-tooltip
                  activator="parent"
                  location="top"
                  color="primary"
                >{{attachment.file_name}}</v-tooltip>
              </v-chip>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="email-body flex-grow-1">
        <iframe :srcdoc="currentEmail?.body" class="w-100 h-100 border-none" id="body-content"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-col>

I am basically emulating a outlook mailbox so the right side column I have posted contains the contact info and body of the email. The email html contains styles that can effect my SPA so it is instead injected via an iframe. I would love to use my applications scrollbars styling instead of the default stylebars in the iframe which are very ugly and do not match. So can I adjust the scrollbar? Or maybe there is a better way to position my CSS for this flex container for the right side?
My css for the scrollbar is as follows:
  /* custom scrollbar */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(var(--v-theme-primaryLighten4));
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
  }


You'll have to get that CSS injected into the iframe then. Either find a way to add it to :srcdoc="currentEmail?.body", or inject it via JavaScript after that document has loaded.

Can you give an answer showing how you would inject ? That is the approach I was thinking as well but not sure how to do so exactly in a clean and consistent manner.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/217776/1427878
